# tikz 3d gets "too many vectors" at commercial printer - detection? fix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, rendering

The 3d marmot included in samcarter's upcoming tugboat article on tikzlings (thanks sc!), which reduces to,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\marmot[3D]}
\end{document}
```

caused an error at TUGboat's commercial printer because of "too many vectors". I'll append the msg from them, although it doesn't say much besides "you overflowed our RIP". (I just replaced the vectorized 3d image with a high-res bitmap for print purposes, to get on with life. TUGboat issue expected to mail Sept 27 btw.)

Not entirely surprising, but the first question is, can such a "too many vectors" problem be detected with Ghostscript? (Or another free tool. Not Acrobat.) I wouldn't expect it to be detected by default, but maybe there is some option that would allow for detecting it? Because I'd rather not send our printer pdfs that they can't print.

And second, is there a way to control the 3d rendering level (whatever that might mean ... how many rays get traced, or whatever) in some way? And maybe it could be decreased by default with no visible effect? I rather doubt that such a terrifically high level so as to overflow a commercial RIP is necessary.

Since I doubt any of this is specific to tikzlings, thought I'd post here. Hope I didn't break too many rules. --karl

From our printer:

> Graphics with heavy amounts of vector points have always been an issue
> for Prepress RIP Engines to process.
>
> A Prepress RIP converts the graphics into raster images for printing.
>
> A raster image is based on x and y coordinates and has to interpret all
> the vector points and place them on that grid.
>
> When there are a huge amount of vector points the RIP struggles to
> perform this process. It is also compounded if that graphic needs to
> trap to other colors on the page or within itself.
>
> Eventually the RIP gives up and errors out.
>
> When the vector points are reduced, the RIP is able to convert the image
> easier because it "averages the position between the two points that are
> further apart."
>
> This issue is not evident in PDF viewers because the PDF is still in a
> vector state, not rastered.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: I suppose the 3d effect is required, do I? If it's the number of (overlapping) shading areas that cause the problem, perhaps one could try reducing the number of shading components in `\marmot[3D]`. An adjustment for corresponding text in tugboat article may be required as well. So, can you test shaded tikz drawings, from simple ones like `\shade[ball color=white] (0,0) circle (2ex);`?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thanks for the reply. how do i "reduce the number of shading components"? unfortunately i cannot test anything because i can't detect the actual failure. yes, the 3d effect was "required" since the point of the picture was to demonstrate it :). how the heck do i start a new paragraph in a comment? anyway, over on github we had more discussion, and using inkscape showed there was no particularly excessive use of paths or anything. so ... strange. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1054

Comment: In the printed version you could convert the vector graphics to bitmap, and in the electronic version you could keep the vector graphics. As long as the resolution is high enough this might be acceptable. This might prevent some from printing the electronic version, but there are worse things than saving some trees.